# unable to install nvidia driver 460 in 20.04.2

Tags: drivers, nvidia, system-installation, ubuntu-drivers

in ubuntu 20.04.2 installing nvidia drivers throws this error. I can't find any broken packages to fix. I have enabled 'restricted' access for the repositories.

```
vanangamudi@karunthulai:~
$ ubuntu-drivers devices

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:06:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v00008086d000008B3sv00008086sd00008070bc02sc80i00
vendor   : Intel Corporation
model    : Wireless 3160 (Dual Band Wireless AC 3160)
manual_install: True
driver   : backport-iwlwifi-dkms - distro free

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:03:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001B81sv00001043sd00008598bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-435 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

vanangamudi@karunthulai:~
$ 
vanangamudi@karunthulai:~
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-460
[sudo] password for vanangamudi: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver-460 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-460 (= 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-extra-460 (= 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-460 (= 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-encode-460 (= 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-utils-460 (= 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-460 (= 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-ifr1-460 (= 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-fbc1-460 (= 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: nvidia-settings but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-compute-460:i386 (= 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-decode-460:i386 (= 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-encode-460:i386 (= 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-ifr1-460:i386 (= 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-fbc1-460:i386 (= 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-gl-460:i386 (= 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Make sure that in Settings -> Software & Updates that the `Proprietary drivers for devices (restricted)` is selected.

Comment: yes. it is enabled also. but not sure why it is not working

Comment: Try doing the `sudo apt update` before installing.